# Handle RST packets as normal connection termination

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I have a service that is listening and consuming TCP messages. I recently came across a device that sends TCP messages but instead of ending the connection in the regular way, e.g. using FIN, it always ends connections using RST, which on my end is seen as a connection aborted by remote host and the data in the socket queue is gone.

During my research I've come across different opinions on whether that's valid/acceptable and have seen some conclusions stating that applications need to start accepting terminations via RST instead of FIN (or both).

My question is, how? As soon as the client sends the RST packet to my server I get winsock error 10054 stating that the connection was aborted by the remote host. At my application level I don't seen to have any control over it since I just get the error at that point.

This results in two possible intermittent outcomes, depending on timing:
 - Data in the queue is processed and then the connection is dropped.
 - The connection is dropped before data can be processed and it is lost.

So I'm trying to do what I can to prevent these RST packets from being seen as aborts and be able to handle the data sitting in the queue consistently.

Comment: I am curious - why use Winsock these days when you could be using TCPClient instead? Seems like most folks have moved on from Winsock. Seems like a TCPClient would work much better for this case. And the support is FAR better, as can be witnessed by the responses to your question.

Comment: Good question, seems like the third-party component we are using relies on Winsock so perhaps it's time to start moving away from that. That said, if you don't mind can you elaborate on how TCPClient (did you mean TCPListener?) would help on this particular issue?

Comment: Try this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/379cca53-9920-4167-bd51-d685b25ac0dc/questions-about-tcpclient-tcplistener-and-socket-classes. It lays things out pretty succinctly.

Comment: I've tried the same scenario only using a TCPListener on the receiving end but the results were the same, the end issue seems to be that the client forces the RST while data is still in flight so it's probably not even managing to send it before the connection is terminated.